# Store data in GridFS(MongoDB) using stream in PHP.

Tags: encryption, php-mongodb

I need to store encrypted files into GridFS using PHP.
So far I've found the following way:

1. Open the file (fopen)
2. Apply a encryption filter (stream_filter_append)
3. Write the encrypted data in a new temporary file (fwrite)
4. Use MongoGridFS::put() to store the encrypted file into GridFS.
5. Remove the temporary file

This approach as the inconvenient to go with a temporary file which can lead to a big lack of performance when dealing with huge files.

Is there any way to get a “writeable” stream  in gridFS in order to merge step 3 and 4 of my above scenario and avoid the temporary file?

In another words, is there any equivalent to MongoGridFSFile::getResource  but for “write” purpose?

Comment: There is not, as you can see from the [class synopsis](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.mongogridfs.php#mongogridfs.synopsis) in the API docs. You could use the `MongoGridFS::storeBytes` function if you can compile the encrypted byte stream into a string, thus avoiding a temporary file.  In Python, there exists classes that will imitate a file while keeping the data in memory - there might be such a thing for PHP but I'm not knowledgeable enough about PHP to recommend something.